# How to declare global type alias in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I have an alias `type ReactMouseEvent = React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>`

I create a `globals.d.ts` in `types` folder in my project:

```
// in globals.d.ts
import React = require('react')
declare type ReactMouseEvent = React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>
```

and set `typeRoots` in tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "typeRoots": [
            "node_modules/@types",
            "./types"
        ]
    }
}
```

then I try this code:

```js
public setPosition(ev: ReactMouseEvent) {
    console.log(ev)
}
```

but VSCode still complains about missing name `ReactMouseEvent`. How do I solve this problem?

Update: I tried another way to define type in `d.ts`:

```js
import React = require('react')

declare global {
  type ReactMouseEvent = React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, MouseEvent>
}
```

but this doesn't work too :(

Comment: It looks good to me. Have you restarted VSCode after editing the `tsconfig.json`? I've noticed that sometimes VSCode does not "reload" when I edit this file.

Comment: @Hugo Hi, I restarted VSCode immediately after editing config but still no luck...

Comment: Can you share full tsconfig file? In my projects, my declarations files are in `src/` root (I have: `"include": ["./src/**/*"],`) and it works without setting any custom `typeRoots` option in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: @Hugo Hi, I found what I got wrong... I added `"exclude": ["./types"]` to `tsconfig.json` but I can't remember when I did this. Thanks for your hint of `tsconfig.json`. Since StackOverflow does not allow accept a comment please add your answer so that I can accept it :)

Comment: ahah sure, thanks. Glad you found 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my projects, my declarations files are in src/ root (I have: "include": ["./src/**/*"],) and it works without setting any custom typeRoots option in tsconfig.json

Maybe you should check the other fields of your tsconfig file? (make sure you include / not exclude the file)